# Styling td with max-width (%) and width (px) won't work

Tags: css, html-table, width

I would like a td (one of two inside a tr) to be 120px wide but only as long as 120px are not more than 25%.

`<td style="width:120px; max-width:25%">` somehow doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

To make it clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q8dw/1/

Comment: In this scenario the max-width of 25% is equal to .25 of 200px which is 50px; which is lower than the width: value.

Comment: I thought max-width would limit the width in case the width is larger than the max-width

Comment: @JackWilliams In your first comment you pointed out that in this scenario "max-width [...] is lower than the width"/"width is > max-width", ergo max-width should limit the width, shouldn't it? Oh man, I thought I understood CSS...

Comment: I got muddled up, sorry. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp), for a clearer explanation of max-width and how to use it.